# How to get the values of multiple checkboxes and send values to server in android

Tags: java, android, json, checkbox

I'm working on a program in Android Studio. I am trying to get the values from multiple checkboxes (35) and put them into a JSON so I can send it to a server. 
Here is the `SetMethod` to get the selected values of the checkboxes:

```
private void setExtensionForwardNumber(){

    priorityResponse.priorityOne.getTimeTable().mon = verifyCheckbox(priorityOneMon);
    priorityResponse.priorityOne.getTimeTable().tue = verifyCheckbox(priorityOneTue);
    priorityResponse.priorityOne.getTimeTable().wed = verifyCheckbox(priorityOneWed);
    priorityResponse.priorityOne.getTimeTable().thu = verifyCheckbox(priorityOneThur);
    priorityResponse.priorityOne.getTimeTable().fri = verifyCheckbox(priorityOneFri);
    priorityResponse.priorityOne.getTimeTable().sat = verifyCheckbox(priorityOneFri);
    priorityResponse.priorityOne.getTimeTable().sun = verifyCheckbox(priorityOneSun);
    String s = priorityResponse.toJsonObject();
    setForwardExternalFragment(s);

}
```

Here is the function that verifies if the checkbox is checked or not:

```
private boolean verifyCheckbox(CheckBox checkbox) {
    boolean selected = checkbox.isChecked();
    if(selected)
        checkbox.setChecked(true);
    else
        checkbox.setChecked(false);
    return selected;
}
```

I tried to not use the function `verifyCheckbox`, and I used `checkbox.isChecked()`, but I got the same result.

```
priorityResponse.priorityOne.getTimeTable().tue = priorityOneTue.isChecked();
```

The problem is when I receive the value on the server, I get mixed values. Example: If I checked mon,wed,fri,sun, on the server the selected values are: mon,tue,wed,thu,sun. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing. Attach a check listener on every checkbox and append the checkbox values to a global variable. And send the appended values to the server.

```
String str; //global variable.

priorityOneTue = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.priorityOneTue);

priorityOneTue.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        str += "tue";
    }

});
```

Then send str to the server

```
 setForwardExternalFragment(str);
```

Comment: but i have 35 checkboxes. I don`t think that is the good method to do for each checkboxes.

Comment: This is the correct way of coding if you need the order in which each checkbox is checked.

Comment: I hope the answer i gave is the one you are looking for. Thanks.

Comment: It still don t work. I think the problem is how I put data in JsonObject.